How to make dynamic reports with a Firebird DB?
I have a large Firebird database containing details of thousands of individual custom product orders.  What are the best options to create reports of these orders that can be filtered and sorted?  We have an old Delphi application using FastReports that we use now, but it only gives static PDFs and doesn't meet our needs well.
We would like to be able to quickly view orders based on various conditions and be able to filter and sort them.
The DB is hosted locally, so it doesn't need to be cloud or web based.
We will hire someone to implement this, but would like to know what the best options are so we can research before deciding.
FastReports can generally provide the right views, but they are static and a huge hassle to create new reports.

How is data feed to FastReport? I'm guessing there is some database query behind. So your first step should be adding ability to modify this query. After that you can work on changing existing or creating new reports.

It seems you need an OLAP solution, like FastCube, https://www.fast-report.com/products/analysis-vcl

Some grid controls provide such functionality as well (sort, group, filter etc). One example is Developer Express VCL Data Grid It is a bit heavy and has a learning curve to use all features.

FastReport is not static. It can use parameters and widely modify behavior and appearance on their base. But it looks like you rather need a query builder with showing results in grid rather than report tool.

If you want have a Live Reporting Tool for "playing around" with your Data, than you should go with the DevExpress Tools that are available. like @Brian Said, use VCL Data Grid or go with the Pivot component from DEV Express. If you want to have a Printable result, stay with Fastreport and use a QueryBuilder to sort and filter your data.
